# Sails + Redis = flash & csrf don't work

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js, csrf

I added the following packets in my package.json :

- redis
- connect-redis

I uncommented

```
adapter: 'connect-redis',
```

in my config/session.js

If I do all of this, server starts and this warning disappears from terminal :

```
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

But CSRF that I activated in my config/csrf.json doesn't work anymore and the code I use with sails-hook-flash doesn't work either.

For this line

```
req.addFlash("success","Created !");
```

I have the following error

```
addFlash is not a function
```

Of course, before activating Redis, the error didn't occure.
How to configure sails and Redis properly ? Or maybe should I use something else than Redis ? Can you show me a tutorial because I don't really understand ?

Comment: Did you also comment out the line `adapter: 'memory'` in the config/session.js file?

Comment: Can you please provide the sails.js version?

Comment: Glen, I don't have such a line. Then I tried to add it, but if I launch my app in production I again have this error : "Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process."

logout, I'm running sails 0.12.14